# ASP.NET Core: Cancelled tasks get stuck in IIS Worker Process, causing application to be un-responsive to the users

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-middleware

At the time of high user traffic, the server struggles to keep up with the user requests, which causes the users to refresh the page one or more time. This causes the cancelled tasks to pile up in the IIS Worker Process untill the pilled up requests reach the application's Queue Length limit defined in the Application Pool configuration, at this point the application becomes un-responsive and we have to manually stop the application in the IIS then end it's respective process from the Task Manager and then start the application again, which resolves the issue.But this is causing significant problems as the session gets lost, and we cant afford that. [image: Attached image of the IIS Worker Process]

Initially, I read various articles from which I learned that this might be happening due to unhandled exceptions or due to session locking so I removed both these issues, by using cookies for writting stuff which I was writting in the session and using a middleware to handle all the unhandled exceptions. We have tested the middleware and it works as intended for all the other exceptions and the requests don't pile up in the IIS worker process, this only happens when the page is refreshed during a long running request.
This is my code for the exception handler.

```
    public class ErrorHandlerMiddleware : IMiddleware
    {
        private readonly IErrorLogger errorLogger;

        public ErrorHandlerMiddleware(IErrorLogger errorLogger) => this.errorLogger = errorLogger;
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
        {
            try
            {
                await next(context);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                 
        await errorLogger.LogExceptionAsync(ex);
                await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
                 
            }
        }

        private static async Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { exception.Message, exception.StackTrace })); 
        }
    }
```

What can i do so that the cancelled tasks get handled in the middleware as well ?

Comment: Before moving further to such articles on tips, try to use a performance profiler to identify the actual bottleneck, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/diagnostic-tools?view=aspnetcore-7.0 You can easily find the solutions once the culprit is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You handle the canceled task by using below code:

```
public class ErrorHandlerMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    private readonly IErrorLogger errorLogger;

    public ErrorHandlerMiddleware(IErrorLogger errorLogger) => this.errorLogger = errorLogger;

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        try
        {
            await next(context);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // Handle cancellation exception
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Request cancelled.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await errorLogger.LogExceptionAsync(ex);
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
        }
    }

    private static async Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { exception.Message, exception.StackTrace }));
    }
}
```

or you could try timeout:

```
catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        // The task was canceled.
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout;
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Request was canceled.");
    }
```